# Use a USB joystick from C++

Tags: c++, directinput, joystick

In my project I'm using directinput to manage the joysticks attached to the PC and it works, but IMHO directimput is terrible to understand and manage perfectly...

Does some other library/method exist to manage the joysticks in C++ in a more pretty mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/)

Comment: @ghiboz:  If you're looking for documentation, check the Ogre3D website.  The libraries are independent of each other, but the projects seem to be closely related.  And while the Ogre3D website has a megaton of documentation and tutorials, the OIS website has nothing.

Comment: thanks, but I dont understand, in the ogre there is some stuff for the ois documentation??

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: It would be a good idea to add some more information to your answer. Just a link is not really an answer.